# RTSP vs. HTTP for audio streaming

Tags: http, streaming, rtsp, icecast

I have installed an Icecast server to simulate a radio station. Icecast use HTTP as a protocol but I wonder if, for audio only, it provides a good enough sound quality. I've heard about RTSP and it seems more convenient for audio streaming - but I can't find any Icecast equivalent using RTSP protocols.

Can I have your thoughts on it?

Thanks!

Comment: When choosing protocol, your main concern here is client compatibility.  HTTP is compatible with just about everything, where as RTSP is not.  The transport protocol has no bearing on audio quality... that's up to the codec used and its configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of HTTP with protocols that support adaptive bitrates. This is theoretically a bad fit... however, HTTP is widely interoperable. It has countless implementations both on the server and client sides, which is great.
RTSP isnt known for its interoperability... Normal RTSP servers close inactive control connections. Well-behaving servers will still keep RTSP sessions for a while longer than HTTP...

Comment: What would you reckon therefore? Can I stick to HTTP and still have a good quality of sound and not too many issues? What do you mean by "a bad fit"?

Comment: Since HTTP with TCP (transport protocols) is designed for reliable delivery rather than keeping up a steady flow, but with the prevalence of high-speed connections these days it doesn't matter so much ;) HTTP can only seek byte ranges, not time offsets so for audio streaming I reckon HTTP should be fine. The only real reason you should use RTP/RTSP is because their session may contain multiple streams to be combined at the receiver's end; for example, audio and video may be on separate channels.

Comment: @OlivierLaflamme Technically speaking you can see time ranges with HTTP.  It just isn't commonly done.  Also, you can send any container format you want over HTTP, so having multiple channels of audio and video is possible.  Easier yet, there are segmented standards like DASH and HLS which implement this directly.

Comment: @Brad thanks, I totally agree! I actually forgot that you could see time ranges with HTTP :), hope this extra information helps OP, seeing that I could have been more thorough in my explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Audio quality depends on the codec and it's bit-rate. Transport is pretty much irrelevant.